# Android Application works fine on emulator but not on a real device

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I run the program on an AVD and it works fine when i alter the virtual sensors but it fails to function on a real device.

The real device just shows 0.0 as the pressure.

I have also added the following permissions in the manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Here is the main java class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{

public Sensor TemperatureSensor;
public SensorManager sensorManager;
public float pressurereading = 0;
public TextView Textfield;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().SENSOR_SERVICE);
    TemperatureSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
    Textfield = findViewById(R.id.Textfield);
    Textfield.setText(String.valueOf(pressurereading));
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,TemperatureSensor,SensorManager
            .SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int Accuracy) {

}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    pressurereading = e.values[0];
    Textfield.setText(String.valueOf(pressurereading));
}
}
```

Here is the xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Device Temperature"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:id="@+id/Textfield"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Logcat for a successful build on a real device.

```
06-20 23:13:42.009 8881-8881/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-20 23:13:42.057 8881-8881/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
06-20 23:13:42.261 8881-8881/lenovo.learning W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/lenovo.learning-1/lib/arm64
06-20 23:13:42.275 8881-8881/lenovo.learning I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-20 23:13:42.345 8881-8881/lenovo.learning W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-20 23:13:42.361 8881-8881/lenovo.learning D/AccessibilityManager: current package=lenovo.learning, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=true, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
06-20 23:13:42.443 8881-8881/lenovo.learning E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
06-20 23:13:42.488 8881-8910/lenovo.learning I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 74bd0df, Ida1be052e0
Build Date                       : 11/27/17
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.14.00.04
Local Branch                     : 
Remote Branch                    : 
Remote Branch                    : 
Reconstruct Branch               : 
06-20 23:13:42.491 8881-8910/lenovo.learning I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
06-20 23:13:42.493 8881-8910/lenovo.learning I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-20 23:13:42.494 8881-8910/lenovo.learning D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-20 23:13:42.525 8881-8881/lenovo.learning W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Comment: What do you see on logcat?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS
I have added Logcat in the question. Please check. 
Thanks!

Comment: this is on your real device?

Comment: Does the real device have a pressure sensor?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS i have updated with a new Logcat, Please check and Thanks!

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Thank you for your time, my device does'nt have a pressure sensor.Thanks!

Comment: @DataDino Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused by real device not having the proper sensor type. According to the documentation of SensorManager, getDefaultSensor(int) will return

> the default sensor matching the requested type **if one exists** and the application has the necessary permissions, or **null otherwise**.

If you end up passing `null` to `sensorManager.registerListener` no events would be fired, therefore `onSensorChanged` will never be called.

Comment: Thanks, the device was not having the sensor.